# How do we get the negative voltage input value of this Op-Amp?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, kirchhoffs-laws

This is an exercise we did in class about the linear limitations of an Op-Amp, I get how we get the conductance and the Current value. But I don't understand in this KVL how did we get the value of $$V_a = -R_3 I^+_{IB} - V_{IO} $$ It's at the right of R1 for those who didn't see it.
[image]

Comment: You're asking about a \$V_a\$ but nowhere in this image is there any reference to a \$V_a\$. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Oh maybe it's not very visible it's at the right of R_1

Comment: oh, okay. Well, go back to what you know about op amps with negative feedback: what's the relationship between the voltage at the inverting node and the voltage at the non-inverting node?

Comment: We consider that they are equal so if we find the voltage of the non-inverting node we find the voltage of the inverting node right? So now we transform R3 and the source of current that are in parallel into a Voltage source in series with the resistor. So now we sum the two voltage sources. And bot of the values have a negative sign because the current isn't going into the input?

Comment: @Nuz The approach is to assume that the opamp can keep the two inputs equal, work out what you expect if that is the case, and then see if you can invalidate what you find out based on the assumption. If you do invalidate it, then you know the assumption is false and you go a different direction. For these purposes, you assume the opamp's \$V_-=V_+\$. So start by assuming \$V_a=V_+\$. Here, it's easy. Just convert the Norton current source and resistor to its Thevenin equivalent and assume there's no loading. You should easily get that equation you show at the outset.

Comment: @jonk This is what I just said in the comment right before you isn't it?

Comment: Yup. But your question asks about how to get the equation. Given your stated knowledge, which I agree with, my suggestion about how to approach that equation from that starting point would seem to me to leave almost nothing left to do in answering your own question. If what is left isn't obvious at this point, I'm a little worried I guess.